# Which website builder or CMS is recommended for a resume website?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-development, web

I have been asked to create a website for someone trying to break into the creative field. They are looking to post their resume, writing samples, video, audio, and eventually have an online store, with static content like an 'about' page etc. mixed in.

I work as a developer, but I develop from-scratch applications on top of an XML database written in XQuery. I do both back-end and front-end development in this capacity, so I know HTML, CSS, and JQuery. I've designed sites using Bootstrap and I also have experience working with Drupal.

The client had an old website up online that was built on WordPress and hosted by a friend of his. I don't have experience with WordPress, but tried playing around with it anyway and found I didn't like it. I thought maybe trying Wix would work in this case, so it'd be quick and easy to get up online and the client could potentially easily update content himself. But, I was told that Wix is bad for SEO and no professional sites are built using it. I originally wanted to just build a new site from scratch, since that's what I'm used to doing anyway, but was again told that doing so would be re-inventing the wheel and also not good for SEO. I don't have a lot of experience with SEO.

Long story short, I'm looking for recommendations on frameworks/site builders that are relatively easy to use, have a store option built-in/available, and work well for professional sites. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the wizard at http://cmsmatrix.org/ although Drupal sounds just fine (and we have a [sister site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to it)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Hugo. I personally used it and is very easy to maintain the project.

There are also some themes for resumes: https://themes.gohugo.io/tags/resume/

Answer (score 0):

For content management use headless cms. strapi and directus for the back end and front end using apis with react, jquery or static site generators like gatsby & jekyll. these are easy to maintain and most importantly they are fast. for resume / portfolio / blogs even large contain base site will work smooth in such JAM Stack. But none of them comes with built in store or payment option built in.

on the other hand you can convert Prestashop or Opencart which are actually built for ecommerce into resume /  portfolio site with store.